# Pass psql trigger variables to python script

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers

I am checking for changes on a database table and running a python script.
Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION callMyFooFunc()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python3', '/var/lib/postgresql/foo.py'])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

and here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER executePython 
AFTER UPDATE ON public."FooTable" 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE callMyFooFunc();
```

Everything is working. The foo.py is executed.
How can I pass the psql "variables/arguments" to my foo.py? Things like tg_op, NEW etc.

In the foo.py I want to process the "changed" data.

Comment: This [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-trigger.html) article should answer your question. I am not sure however that spawning a process within a trigger is a good idea at all.

Comment: It's working. Great: import subprocess subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python3', '/var/lib/postgresql/foo.py'], env={'name':TD["new"]["Name"]})